# Выключение режима не беспокоить

Tags: java, android

Начальные условия: телефон находится в режиме "Не беспокоить".
Необходимо, чтобы при звонке с определенного номера телефон автоматически перешел в Нормальный режим.
Собственно сам процесс определения номера и переключения режима происходит нормально. Проблема в том, что телефон при этом все равно молчит. 
Мне кажется что это то-же самое, что при звонке нажать кнопку громкости.
Есть ли какие-нибудь другие варианты включения нормального режима, чтобы играла мелодия вызова?

На всякий случай мой код:

```
public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    Boolean Ringing = false;
    String phoneNumber;
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLog";

    public CallReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){

            String phone_state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG,"phone_state " + phone_state); // состояние телефона (звонит / не звонит)

            if (phone_state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) { // телефон звонит, получаем входящий номер
                phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG,"CALL_STATE_RINGING " + phoneNumber); // входящий номер

                Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
                dbHelper = contacts.new DBHelper(context);

                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Ringing  " + Ringing); // входящий номер
            } else {
                Ringing = false;
                Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Ringing  " + Ringing); // входящий номер
            }
            saveSett(context);
        }
    }
```

переключение режима делаю в сервисе так:

```
myAM.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT); // включение режима только важные

myAM.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL); // включение нормального режима
```

Comment: как по мне, вообще странно, что любое приложение может выключить этот режим...

Comment: как по мне, то это комментарий стоит адресовать Гуглу